# Difference between memory_get_peak_usage and actual php process' memory usage

Tags: memory-management, php

Why result of php memory_get_peak_usage differs so much from memory size that is shown as allocated to process when using 'top' or 'ps' commands in Linux?

I've set 2 Mb of memory_limit in php.ini
My single-string php-script with

```
echo memory_get_peak_usage(true);
```

says that it is using 786432 bytes (768 Kb)

If I try to ask system about current php process

```
echo shell_exec('ps -p '.getmypid().' -Fl');
```

it gives me

```
F S UID        PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN    RSS PSR STIME TTY          TIME CMD
5 S www-data 14599 14593  0  80   0 - 51322 pipe_w  6976   2 18:53 ?        00:00:00 php-fpm: pool www
```

RSS param is 6976, so memory usage is 6976 * 4096 = 28573696 = ~28 Mb

Where that 28 Mb come from and is there any way to decrease memory size that is being used by php-fpm process?

Answer (score 5):

The memory size is mostly used by the PHP process itself. `memory_get_peak_usage()` returns the memory used by your specific script. Ways to reduce the memory overhead is to remove the number of extensions, statically compile PHP, etc.. But don't forget that php-fpm (should) fork and that a lot of the memory usage that's not different between PHP process is in fact shared (until it changes).

Comment: Thanks. So if I open  '/proc/*pid*/status' and see VmExe: 7508 kB VmLib: 18328 kB, does that mean that in fact VmLib are common for all php processes? In other words 3 processes with 25 Mb each in fact occupy not 25 + 25 + 25 = 75 Mb but 18 + 7 + 7 + 7 = 39 Mb ?

Comment: No way of telling. After a fork many things will likely be shared, but it may not ^_^. My understanding is that initially everything use identical memory locations, but as soon as the fork changes the memory a copy-on-write occurs. I have no idea if you can read that out from ps to tell you to the truth.

Answer (score 1):

PHP itself may only be set to a 2meg limit, but it's running WITHIN a Apache child process, and that process will have a much higher memory footprint.

If you were running the script from the command line, you'd get memory usage of PHP by itself, as it's not wrapped within Apache and is running on its own.

Comment: thanks. You see from example that I run PHP as CGI application, so no Apache is used

Comment: Actually, your example hints that it IS being run under Apache, as the username is www-data

Comment: That doesn't prove anything. php-fpm runs under www-data as well

Comment: Also note that even with Apache processes, most of the memory is shared between all children because Apache forks children from the master process that already has `mod_php` loaded so that part of the memory is shared. If you use recent enough `top`, look at fields `RSan` vs `RSsh` vs `USED`. I think `RSan` is closest to actual memory consumption for a single child. If you want even more accurate, you have to compute PSS, or Proportional Set Size per process.

Answer (score 0):

The peak memory usage is for the current script only.