# php memory_get_peak_usage() includes mysql memory usage?

Tags: php, mysql, memory-management

In PHP there is a function **memory_get_peak_usage** which returns the peak memory used by the current php process.

I want to know if it also includes the memory consumed by mysql queries which were fired by the php process?

Comment: Pretty sure no, as those aren't part of the PHP process.

Comment: See thees interesting approaches: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273517/difference-between-memory-get-peak-usage-and-actual-php-process-memory-usage

Comment: The only memory usage included relative to mysql is the amount used by the returning result-set and your processing.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to know if it also includes the memory consumed by mysql queries which were fired by the php process?

If you fetched results from those queries, and PHP needed to allocate memory as a result of that fetching, then yes, results from a database query **will** be included in that memory use figure.  It will *not* include memory used by MySQL itself, nor will it include memory used by query results that are not fetched.

This is true of [`memory_get_peak_usage`](http://php.net/memory_get_peak_usage) *and* [`memory_get_usage`](http://php.net/memory_get_usage).

Answer (score -1):

The documentation says it does not.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-peak-usage.php

Also it does not make sense for this function to include that memory. As this function shows the peak of the script. Also take a look at the user comment which is helpful imo.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-peak-usage.php#98734

Comment: -1, blatantly false.  The documentation does not expressly say that query results are not included in memory use.

Comment: Nor does it say that it includes it, therefor one can consider it not included.